# Case creator when creating a Case from outlook side panel

Tags: email2case, salesforce-for-outlook

I'm using the outlook side panel and I've added two outlook email routing addresses for two users that want to open cases from the panel.
While, when they create a case they are being assigned the ownership (as it is configured in the outlook routing definition) the case creator is always set to the default Case creator.

How can I configure the Cases created from a users's outlook to show him/her as the creator?

Answer (score 1):

If each user of the Outlook panel is using a unique email routing address, you can change the ownership via workflow rule once the case is in Salesforce to map the inbound email address to the correct user.

Comment: My issue is with the case creator not the owner